# String return from regex can not be found in another string using in operator python

Tags: python, regex, string, in-operator

I am learning about regex at the moment and I am having a hard time debugging. My goal is that given a string which contains multiple ratios or ratios alike format, extract all the correct ratio with the format x+:x+ (+ means multiple digits). This is my code below:

```
string= "2890.1:2004 1.45.7 2890.6:2009 505.204:908.890 1:100 0.55:1 10:59:40"

#empty string declaration
other_str = str()
time_str = str()
ratio_str = str()

#pattern for ratio, time and other format
pattern_ratios = re.compile(r'1:[-+]?[0-9]+')
pattern_time = re.compile(r'[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+')
pattern_other = re.compile(r'\d*\.?\d+:\d*\.?\d+')

#create irritable re.match object
matches_ratios = pattern_ratios.finditer(string)
matches_time = pattern_time.finditer(string)
matches_other = pattern_other.finditer(string)

#create a time string to store all time format found
for time_match in matches_time:
    time_str += string[time_match.span()[0]:time_match.span()[1]] + ' '
print('time string =',time_str)

#create a other string to store all other format found
for other_match in matches_other:
    other_str += string[other_match.span()[0]:other_match.span()[1]] + ' '
print('other string =', other_str)

#create a ratio string to store all ratio format found
for ratio_match in matches_ratios:
    ratio = string[ratio_match.span()[0]:ratio_match.span()[1]]
    print('\nratio =',ratio)
    print('not in other string:',ratio not in other_str)
    print('not in time string:',ratio not in time_str)
    if (ratio not in other_str and ratio not in time_str):
        ratio_str += ratio + ' '

print('ratio list =',ratio_str.split())
```

The output is:

> time string = 10:59:40
>   other string = 2890.1:2004 2890.6:2009
>   505.204:908.890 1:100 0.55:1 10:59
>
> ratio = 1:2004
>   not in other string: False
>
> not in time string: True
>
> ratio = 1:100
>   not in other string: False
>
> not in time string: True
>
> ratio list= []

Which is an unexpected output because from my understanding, if I do this in 2 different string like below:

```
str1 = '2890.1:2004 2890.6:2009 505.204:908.890 1:100 0.55:1 10:59'
str2 = '1:2004'
str2 in str1
```

The output is True!
Is it something have to do with the in-operator itself?

Comment: `str2` is in `str1`, so `True` is correct.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't it work with string returned from my regex? That is my question

Comment: Which string are you talking about?

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific. If you look at the output, the ratio string is empty. The ratio list is just ratio_str.split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `and` where you should be using `or`:

```
if (ratio not in other_str or ratio not in time_str):
        ratio_str += ratio + ' '
```

This should give you the result:

```
ratio list = ['1:2004', '1:100']
```

Comment: There are other ways you can do it as well, (eg. `if (ratio in other_str and ratio not in time_str): ratio_str += ratio + ' '`, it really depends on what exactly you want to return. Notice I still used `and` but changed one `not in` to `in` in one case, so you'll want to test each case of where you want to return the substring. The `or` is fairly versatile though, so it should do what you want :)